# Bootstrap textbox dropbox search

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap template and I have recently added a text box to the top of my navigation bar. I would like it to show a dropdown list of items when something is searched in it, So like it auto shows a list as they type. Auto show without clicking search and going to another page or anything. Is there any way to do it?

For the people who say 'What have you tried so far' literally nothing.. As there is not anything out there to help me, I have spent hours trying to get an answer and have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

You mean an `autocomplete`, like **TypeAhead**?

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

As demo shows, you just need to use its class and call the script:

```
<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>
```

--

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substrRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
        // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
        matches.push({ value: str });
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```